# How to Configure Solution Code Analysis for Xamarin Projects

Tags: xamarin, static-code-analysis

I have solution code analysis configured for ALL projects and I have verified that ALL projects ALL configurations ALL platforms are referencing the correct ruleset file. However, the Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects are not running the rules.

Is it possible to use ruleset files with Xamarin projects? If so how do I fix the issue of the rules not running?